# C++ Qt preserve order of operation: update QLabel before moving on

Tags: c++, qt, pthreads, qt4

In a part of the code (as shown below), the label updates with the text **after** the generate function in next line has finished working. I need the label to update before starting the generate begins working.

```
void myDialog::my_custom_slot()
{
   emit someLabel->setVisible(true);
   emit someLabel->setText("Some Text...");

   string result = func.generate_str(); // operation takes 5 to 10 second
}
```

I'm still learning the basics of Qt. My program is quit straight forward with no additional threaded activities. My guess so far has been that the Qt's threading are doing some interesting things, but I'm not sure how to get the desired outcome.

Using Qt 4.8, Ubuntu 16.04, compile process: `qmake -project`, `qmake`, `make`. Using .ui file generated with Qt designer, someLabel comes from the generated ui_...h file and myDialog has a is-a relationship with the generated .h file and QDialog. func.generate_str() comes from a local #include "..." and instance func. Every other parts of the program works successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Your label is not updated as the main thread can't get back to the event loop before it enters the generate_str() function.

You could hack around this by using `QApplication::processEvents()` after changing the label

2. You have a function call that takes between 5 and 10 seconds running on the main thread in a GUI program, meaning your application will be "frozen" for that duration.

For that problem you can either consider running the function concurrently, e.g. with a thread, or spitting it in many smaller steps, letting the main thread do its main work (event processing) while it walks through the steps one-by-one

Comment: I understand now, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

UI operations usually aren't completed synchronously. Try scheduling `func.generate_str()` in the next iteration of the event loop or even a little later. Something like this might work:

`QTimer::singleShot(0, [&]{ func.generate_str(); });`

0 is 0 milliseconds which just means next run loop iteration. The funny syntax of the second argument is a C++ lambda (since C++11).

Comment: I'm getting these error: `error: no matching function for call to ‘QTimer::singleShot(int, myDialog::generate_str()::<lambda()>)’`

Doing  `QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(func.generate_str()));` seems to make compiler happy but generate_str is not a slot, and I also need a way to get the return result from the generate_str function, that I don't see how I may do in this format.

Comment: I have also tried a delaying: `std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));` which did not fix the issue.

Comment: You need to let the loop finish. Sleeping won't help execute the UI updates you queued up as that loop run needs to complete before you'll see updates. Check this answer out on how to make a slot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544665/qtimersingleshot-looks-for-the-specified-slot-in-the-given-objects-parent-c

Comment: I have created a custom slot like the link and before the func.generate_str() line, I added `QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(temp()));`

Comment: (since I don't have comment editing privilege) which did not fix the issue.

Comment: What is happening? You're not seeing "Some text..." in the label? What are you seeing?

Comment: @dbv the functor based connects are only available from Qt5 on, so for Qt4.8 this would need another slot which then calls the function